# prestashop 1.6 localhost redirects to live url

Tags: redirect, prestashop-1.6

I have a prestashop store.I have downloaded the source from ftp and imported the database as well.I want to set it up on my localhost.I am using wamp on windows 7.I have set my db credentials in setting.inc.php.When I access the front end it redirects me to the live url.The admin is ok ie its accessing through localhost.

I have edited the ps_shop_url table and changed the domain and domainssl to localhost and physical url to /myproject/.

I have also changed the ps_configuration table and changed PS_SHOP_DOMAIN = localhost and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL=localhost

I have also deleted my .htaccess file.

But the issue is still there.It redirect me to the live url.I have spent alot of time but in vain.Kindly help me I am new to prestashop.I have installed prestashop 1.6 version.

Answer (score 6):

How to migrate PrestaShop from Your web server to local? (and inversely)

25 July 2015  Tutorials
That task is quite easy in most cases. But you must remember about few essential things.

Moving from SERVER to LOCAL PC
I assume you’ve configured PHP, Apache and MySQL on your local machine. If you don’t have those things installed, find some informations about how to do it. If you are using Windows I can suggest you installing XAMPP application.

Download all website files from your FTP and put them to the local directory.

Next, let’s export the database from phpMyAdmin to the .sql file and download it. Import that file to your local database.

Now it’s a time to make some changes in your local database, files and BackOffice.

**Database**:

1. Go to the table `PS_SHOP_URL` and change values of following columns:
   – domain localhost
   – domain_ssl localhost
   – If your PrestaShop is located in some addictional directory, set the value of `physical_uri` (for example, if it’s in the ‘shop’ directory, write /shop/ there)
2. In the `PS_CONFIGURATION` table change the value of `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN` and `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL`

**Files**:

1. Set the debug mode ON in config/defines.inc.php

   define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true)
2. Set your local database parameters in config/settings.inc.php
3. If your PrestaShop is located in some addictional directory (for example /shop/), edit the .htaccess file. It’s located in PrestaShop main folder. Add to this part…

RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:
1
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:
…that directory. Complete code should look like this:

RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/shop/
1
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/shop/
BackOffice:

Advanced Parameters -> Performance
Select “Force compilation” in smarty settings, disable the cache and clear the cache using button located in upper right header of page.

Comment: I addition to these we need to provide permission to cache directory 
chmod -R 755 shop/cache

Comment: In my case, I had to add the port number when editing the database (1.)(2.) ('localhost:8888' instead of 'localhost') for the site to show up in Mamp.

Answer (score 0):

The solution above didn't help on my 1.7 installation. After some debugging I have found, where the redirects originated from. Follows my solution for localhost:

Assuming your local instance of PrestaShop is connected to a local database, change these values:

- in "presta_configuration" table set "PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS" to 0 (ie. turn off "nice" urls)
- in "presta_configuration" table set both "PS_SSL_ENABLED" and "PS_SSL_ENABLED_EVERYWHERE" to 0 (turn off redirecting to https, as you probably don't want it)
- in "presta_shop_url" table set fields "domain" to "localhost" and "domain_ssl" to an empty value